# jquery datepicker prev and next buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery datepicker next/prev images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436124/jquery-datepicker-next-prev-images)

I am using jquery datepicker  ui plugin 1.9.2

I have `prev.png` and `next.png` images, tell please how to make this buttons as background-images of prev and next buttons?

Comment: This will be in the css of the theme you are using with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2):

I used like this :

```
    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev {
        background: url("../images/next-previous.png") no-repeat scroll -2px center transparent;
    }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
        background: url("../images/next-previous.png") no-repeat scroll -18px -2px transparent;
        right: 2px;
    }
```