# Datepicker inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi guys i have some issues on the consistency of datepicker from jQuery. 
I've attached an image.
[browser inconsistency IE / Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zibRY.jpg)

So the problem is that the arrows '<' and '>' that are shown in Chrome are not visible also in IE ... the weird thing is that on IE if i click on the empty space where the arrows normally should be, it works. 
So what i want to do is display in IE the icons.

This is my jquery implementation of the custom style.

```
$(".action-calendar").datepicker({
            nextText: " ",
            prevText: " ",
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var result = [false, '', null]; // dates not clickable because beforeShowDay() is called on each date click
                var dayEvents = $.grep(eventsList, function (event) {
                    return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
                });

                if (dayEvents.length) {
                    var text = $.map(dayEvents, function (a) {
                        return a.Title;
                    }).join("<br>");
                    result = [false, "highlight", text];
                }

                return result;
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                // re-initialize tooltips because when changing month/year the calendar is destroyed and rebuilt
                // (beforeShowDay is called after every month/year change)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    applyTooltips();
                }, 300);
            },
        });

        applyTooltips(); // initialize tooltips
```

BTW i've tried adding some text in

```
extText: " ",
prevText: " ",
```

it does not display anything.
Thank you.

P.S. I'm using IE11 and have no browser console errors, infos, warnings etc

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IE-Version, it might have problems to display the arrow-icons (ui-icon), since they come usually from a icon-font and Some older IE-Versions cannot load or display icon fonts.
The `<a>` or `<button>` beneath will function, but the label on it is not displaying.
For more information try looking into you Browser Dev-Tools (usually f12-Key)

Comment: Okay. IE 11 can perfectly handle icon-fonts.
Did you look at the developer-Console, if it shows any error or warning?

Comment: yep. i have noting in console. also i've loaded in the .cshtml : jquery.dataTables.min.css .... jquery-1.11.3.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Do you have a CSS file for jquery-ui? Because that's the one you need, not datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding icons, which should be consistent across all browsers? Here's another SO response on adding the images: [jQuery datepicker next/prev images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436124/jquery-datepicker-next-prev-images)